# Methods called from OnClickListener not updating member variable

Tags: java, android, eclipse, onclicklistener

I'm banging my head against a wall here... I can't figure out why this isn't working...  I have an android app that basically uses three activities: `MainActivity`, `SummaryViewer` and `WebViewer`.  The `MainActivity` basically consists of four buttons the user can press.  Based on which button is pressed, `SummaryViewer` should start, and corresponding content is displayed in two TextViews within `SummaryViewer`.  The four buttons are "People," "Places," "Events" and "Things."

Content for the `SummaryViewer` class is stored in four different object arrays, with a corresponding name (i.e., mPeople[], mPlaces[], etc.).  In `MainActivity` I have an `onClickListener` set up for each of the four buttons.  Within each `onClickLister`, I have a call to a `setNumType` and an Intent that starts the `SummaryViewer` activity.  Each button does the same thing with regard to calling `SummaryViewer`, but I pass a different integer to `setNumType`, depending on which button is pressed.  So if the People button is pressed, I call `setNumType(1);`, which sets the variable `numType` to "1".  If Places is pressed, I call `setNumType(2);` and so on.

Here's the code from my MainActivity Class:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private Button placesButton; 
private Button peopleButton; 
private Button eventsButton; 
private Button thingsButton; 
private int type; 


public int getNumType(){
    return type; 
}

public void setNumType(int i){
    type = i; 
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    placesButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.places_button); 
    placesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setNumType(1);  
            Intent openSumViewerClass = new Intent("com.tierramaxis.interestingwikipedia.SUMMARYVIEWER"); 
            startActivity(openSumViewerClass);
        }
    });

    peopleButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.people_button); 
    peopleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setNumType(2); 
            Intent openSumViewerClass = new Intent("com.example.SUMMARYVIEWER"); 
            startActivity(openSumViewerClass);
        }
    });

    eventsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.events_button); 
    eventsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setNumType(3); 
            Intent openSumViewerClass = new Intent("com.exmaple.SUMMARYVIEWER"); 
            startActivity(openSumViewerClass);
        }
    });

    thingsButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.things_button); 
    thingsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setNumType(4); 
            Intent openSumViewerClass = new Intent("com.exmple.SUMMARYVIEWER"); 
            startActivity(openSumViewerClass);
        }
    });
}
```

In `SummaryViewer`, I access the `numType` variable, via an object of `MainActivity`, and set it equal to `type`.  `type` then gets passed to two switch statements with corresponding methods and sets the content of the TextViews depending on the value of `type`.  Basically it calls a different object array based upon whether `type` is 1, 2, 3 or 4.  Here's the relevant code from my SummaryViewer Class:

```
public class SummaryViewer extends Activity {

private Button mNextButton; 
private Button mPrevButton; 
private Button mGoButton; 
private TextView mArticleTitle; 
private TextView mArticleSummary;

MainActivity numType = new MainActivity(); 

private int type = numType.getNumType();

//bunch of object arrays for content go in here...

private static int mCurrentIndex = 1;

private void updateTitle(){
    int title = 0; 

    switch (type){

    case 1: title = mInterestingPlaces[mCurrentIndex].getTitle(); 
    mArticleTitle.setText(title); 
    break;

    case 2: title = mInterestingPeople[mCurrentIndex].getTitle(); 
    mArticleTitle.setText(title); 
    break;

    case 3: title = mInterestingEvents[mCurrentIndex].getTitle(); 
    mArticleTitle.setText(title); 
    break;

    case 4: title = mInterestingThings[mCurrentIndex].getTitle(); 
    mArticleTitle.setText(title); 
    break;
    } 
};

private void updateSummary(){
    int summary = 0; 

    switch (type){

    case 1: summary = mInterestingPlaces[mCurrentIndex].getSummary(); 
    mArticleSummary.setText(summary); 
    break;

    case 2: summary = mInterestingPeople[mCurrentIndex].getSummary(); 
    mArticleSummary.setText(summary); 
    break;

    case 3: summary = mInterestingEvents[mCurrentIndex].getSummary(); 
    mArticleSummary.setText(summary); 
    break;

    case 4: summary = mInterestingThings[mCurrentIndex].getSummary(); 
    mArticleSummary.setText(summary); 
    break;
    } 
};

/*public static String updateURL(){
    // this works differently, so I've omitted it to avoid confusion.
};*/

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(null);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewer_summary);

    mArticleTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);         
    mArticleSummary = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.summary); 

    updateTitle();
    updateSummary();


    mNextButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.next_button); 
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex +1) % mInterestingEvents.length; 
            updateTitle(); 
            updateSummary(); 
        }
    });

    mPrevButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.prev_button); 
    mPrevButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex - 1); 
            if (mCurrentIndex < 0) mCurrentIndex = mInterestingEvents.length - 1;
            updateTitle();
            updateSummary(); 
        }
    });

    mGoButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go_button); 
    mGoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent openPageViewer = new Intent("com.example.PAGEVIEWER"); 
            startActivity(openPageViewer);
        }
    });
```

}

Theh problem is `numType` is not being set in `MainActivity` when I call `setNumType` within each `onClickListener`.  When I run the app, everything works, but the TextViews in `SummaryViewer`are blank.  If I set `numType` manually (i.e., initialize it) in `MainActivity`, the variable does get passed, becuase the TextViews in `SummaryActivity` contain the appropriate content.  For example, if I initialize `private int numType = 3` in `MainActivity` then the content in `SummaryViewer` corresponds with `mEvents`, regardless of which button gets pressed.

So it looks to me like the variable `numType` is not being set as it should be based upon each call to `onClickListener` in `MainActivity`

Can someone please help me with this?  I've spent a ridiculous amount of time trying to figure it out.

Comment: `MainActivity numType = new MainActivity();` <= serioulsy? read some guides first ... as many times before I will say: **never create instance of Activity by yourself** ... and one free tip: if you write for android think like there would be **only one Activity at the same time** ... and all you can do is comunicate **via Intents** (well we have also: SharedPreferences or ContentProvider)

Comment: why don´t just pass the type value via intent? It would be a better practise and it will work....

Comment: Thanks... I should have mentioned that I'm still learning and I'm probably in a bit over my head on this...  I'll look up how to pass the variable via an Intent.  Thanks.

Comment: To help you understand whats going on here, the activity created is by the second activity is not the one that sent the intent. You're actually creating a new instance of your main activity, one that hasn't had its buttons clicked, so it never had its numType set.

Comment: Can you explain this further?  I'm a bit confused by what you stated.

Comment: what you did with `MainActivity numType = new MainActivity();` is creating a new instance of the MainActivity object.

Comment: You could compare it to doing `SomeClass myClass = new SomeClass();`
`myClass.setSomeMember("some value");`

then doing `SomeClass myClass2 = new SomeClass();`
and then expecting that `myClass2.getSomeMember();` would return `"some value"`
But since MyClass2 is a new instance of SomeClass, that member isn't set yet

Answer (score 1):

To further explain @Opiatefuchs answer:

**Edited**

in main activity

```
Intent openSumViewerClass = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SummaryViewer.class);
openSumViewerClass.putExtra("numType", 2); 
startActivity(openSumViewerClass);
```

then in SummaryViewer's on create

```
mArticleTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);         
mArticleSummary = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.summary); 

type = getIntent.getIntExtra("numType", 0);

updateTitle();
updateSummary();
```

Comment: Thanks...  when I tried to enter the code you suggested, I get an error message:

"The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<SummaryViewer>) is undefined"

I think this is because I have it under my onClickListener method.  Does it need to go outside of that method?  Also, I can't include "int numType = getIntent.getIntExtra("numType", 0);" in the onCreateMethod of SummaryViewer because I need to pass the int to a method, which is then called in the onCreate method.   

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thanks.  My computer just died, so I can't work on this until I get home.  Wouldn't I need to create an instance of `Intent` in order to use `getIntent` in SummaryViewer?

Comment: No, `getIntent()` is a method defined in the `Activity` class.

If you call this function, you will receive the intent that started this Activity.
In this case, the intent you made in MainActivity.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I got everything working using `Intents`.